# Importance / use / advantages of creating database diagram in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-diagram

I am relatively new to sql server and we are using sql server 2014 version in my workplace. Why do we actually need this database diagram in sql server(using SSMS)?

Comment: To communicate the ideas, both with yourself :) and with your colleagues.

Comment: If I am not wrong in microsoft access editing the relationship diagram allows us to change the primary/foreign key relationship between the tables. Is this the same way the database diagrams works in ssms?

Comment: Don't know about Access, but in SSMS it is possible to mark the key columns and draw the relationships on diagram and have it reflected in the database on save.

Answer (score 1):

A database diagram offers a visualization of the database structure, and that's it's best (and some will probably say only) advantage.

While it is possible to use the diagram to edit the tables, including renaming, adding / removing columns, setting keys and what not, These things are usually best handled using DDL code (of course, if you know what you are doing).

You can think of a database diagram as a [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor for the database schema, and just like most (if not all) WYSIWYG editors, it does have it's drawbacks. 
That's correct for all SSMS designer windows.

In fact, every DBA I know claims that the SSMS designer windows should never be used for designing database objects, and one must always prefer using DDL directly. I can only say I completely agree with this statement.